# To check if all the records of a collection in Oracle are same?

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, nested

I am writing a Oracle Procedure and I have declared a nested array to store some elements. I want to see if all the elements within the collection are same. 
I am open using for loop or a any Oracle Function.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can also use [SET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions177.htm#SQLRF06308) operation:

```
DECLARE
   type num_tab_type  is table of number;
   tab1  num_tab_type := num_tab_type(1,2,3,4);

BEGIN
    IF SET(tab1).COUNT = 1 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line('All elements tab1 are the same');
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Perhaps you are also looking for [IS A SET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52129) which is more the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `multiselect union distinct` with empty instance and then `COUNT`:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   type num_tab_type  is table of number;
   tab1  num_tab_type := num_tab_type(1,2,3,4);
   tab2  num_tab_type := num_tab_type(2,2,2);
   tab_empty num_tab_type := num_tab_type();

   tab num_tab_type;
BEGIN
    tab:= tab1 MULTISET UNION DISTINCT tab_empty;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line('tab1 ' ||  
                    CASE WHEN tab.COUNT IN(0,1) THEN 'all elements are the same' 
                    ELSE 'not all elements are the same' END);

    tab:= tab2 MULTISET UNION DISTINCT tab_empty;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line('tab2 ' || 
                  CASE WHEN tab.COUNT IN(0,1)THEN 'all elements are the same' 
                  ELSE 'not all elements are the same' END);
END;
/
```

Output:

```
tab1 not all elements are the same
tab2 all elements are the same
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Even though it is a  normal requirement , a bit surprised that we have to use without for loop.

Comment: @PranavMohan I expect you could check this in a loop if you really wanted to.